# Finding an example of "A reparametrization of a closed curve need not be closed"$\text{}$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I look at the following exercise of the book "Elementary Differential Geometry" of Andrew Pressley:

"Give an example to show that a reparametrization of a closed curve need not be closed."

Any hints how we could do that? I don't have any idea how to find such an example.

Comment: Circle, $[0,2\pi)$

Comment: Huh? How can a closed curve $\gamma(t)$ become not closed by a different choice of its parameter, giving say $\gamma(s(t))$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pressley's definition is

> A non-constant smooth curve $\gamma : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ is *closed* if there is a real $T \ne 0$ such that $\gamma(t+T) = \gamma(t)$ for all $t$.

Consider the circle $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$. This is closed (with period $T= 2\pi$), but the reparametrization $\gamma(t^3+t)$ is not, since it is not periodic.

Comment: $$\gamma (t^3+t+T)=(\cos ((t^3+t)+T), \sin ((t^3+t)+T))$$ since we know that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are $2\pi$-periodic why doesn't it stand that $$\cos ((t^3+t)+2\pi )=\cos (t^3+t), \ \ \ \ \sin ((t^3+t)+2\pi )=\sin(t^3+t)$$ ?

Comment: @user159870: be careful. Define $\xi(t) = \gamma(t^3 + t)$ and consider $\xi(t+T)$. The first component will be $\cos((t+T)^3 + t + T)$, not $\cos(t^3 + t +T)$.

Comment: $$\xi (t+T)=\gamma ((t+T)^3+t+T)=(\cos ((t+T)^3+t+T),\sin((t+T)^3+t+T))\\ =(\cos ((t+T)^3+t),\sin((t+T)^3+t))=(\cos ((t+T)^3+t),\sin((t+T)^3+t)) \\ =(\cos (t^3+3 t^2 T+3 t T^2+T^3+t), \sin (t^3+3 t^2 T+3 t T^2+T^3+t))$$ Is it correct so far? How can we continue to show that it is not equal to $(\cos t , \sin t)$ ?

Comment: @user159870: If $\xi(t+T) = \xi(t)$, we must have $((t+T)^3 + t + T) - (t^3 + t) = 2 \pi k$ for some integer $k$. But the LHS is a non-constant polynomial in $t$, so it can't be integer-valued for all real inputs $t$.

Comment: Why must it be $$((t+T)^3 + t + T) - (t^3 + t) = 2 \pi k
$$ ?

Comment: @user159870: If $\sin(a) = \sin(b)$ and $\cos(a) = \cos(b)$ then $a,b$ are equivalent angles; i.e. they differ by a multiple of $2 \pi$.

Comment: Ok. Can you give me also an other example of a reparametrization to see if I have understood it?

Comment: @user159870: if you have a closed curve $\gamma$ (or any curve defined on all of $\mathbb R$), any smooth function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $f' > 0$ and $f(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R$ will give you a reparametrization $\gamma(f(t))$. Try $\gamma(e^t - e^{-t})$ for another reparametrization that turns closed curves to non-closed.

Comment: We take $\xi (t)=\gamma (f(t))=\gamma (e^t -e^{-t})$ with $\gamma (t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$. We assume that $\gamma (f(t))$ is $T$-periodic, then $$\xi (t+T)=\xi (t) \Rightarrow \gamma (e^{t+T}-e^{-t-T})=\gamma (e^t -e^{-t}) \\ \Rightarrow (\cos (e^{t+T}-e^{-t-T}), \sin (e^{t+T}-e^{-t-T}))=(\cos (e^t -e^{-t}), \sin (e^t -e^{-t}) ) \\ \Rightarrow  (e^{t+T}-e^{-t-T})-(e^t -e^{-t}) =2k \pi \\ \Rightarrow (e^T -1)e^t+(-e^{-T}+1)e^{-t}=2k \pi \\ \Rightarrow (e^T -1)e^t+e^{-T}(-1+e^T)e^{-t}=2k \pi \\ \Rightarrow (e^T -1) [ e^t+e^{-T}e^{-t}]=2k \pi$$ 

Why can this equality not stand?

Comment: @user159870: since the LHS is continuous, the RHS is too, so $k$ must be constant and thus the LHS is constant too. But clearly the LHS is not constant - e.g. differentiate it and check almost any $t$.

Comment: Why does $k$ have to be a constant if we want $2 k \pi$ to be continuous?

Comment: Because $k$ is integer-valued.

Comment: I don't understand why $k$ must be constant because the RHS is continuous. If we have i.e. $2x, x>0$ it is continuous independently if $x$ is a constant or not.

Comment: @user159870: $k$ must be an *integer* for *all* $t$. If $k(0)=1$ and $k(1)=2$ then continuity implies $k$ would have to take the non-integer value 1.5 for some $t \in (0,1)$.

Comment: I am sorry, I may be stupid right now. But I don't understand how why from the continuity of the left side we conclude that $k$ is a constant. Could you explain it in an other way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30695/discussion-between-anthony-carapetis-and-user159870).

Comment: That is an awful definition of closed curve. A curve should be closed independent of the parametrization. However, using that definition, you are correct.

Comment: @robjohn: agreed.

Comment: Thank you ! I understand it!