# A reparametrization of a closed curve need not be closed?

Tags: differential-geometry

Give an example to show that a reparametrization of a closed curve need not be closed.

The exact same question was asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485639/finding-an-example-of-a-reparametrization-of-a-closed-curve-need-not-be-closed), but I'm more interested in RobJohn's comment under the accepted answer.

When I first saw this question, I thought okay I have a closed curve, say $$\gamma(t)=(a\cos(t),b\sin(t)),\space\text{with}\space t\in\mathbb{R}$$ the ellipse. It is clearly nonconstant, and has period $T=2\pi>0\in\mathbb{R}$. This is the definition of closed in Presseley's book. To me, it seems pretty clear that a periodic curve must be closed or separate the plane into  $2$ pieces, inside the closed curve and outside. So at first this definition of closed curve made sense.

But intuitively, how can *any* reparametrization of an ellipse not be closed? Wouldn't this mean that the reparametrization and the ellipse have different images, contrary to the notion of reparametrization
?

Why *does* Pressely define it this way? And still, what reparametrization map $\phi$ will suffice to show if $\gamma$ is closed, $\gamma(\phi)=\gamma'$ is not closed?

Comment: They define *closed* to be a property of a *parametrized curve*. They make the distinction between *parametrized curve* and just *curve* as the topological space which is image of a parametrized curve, but then they inconsistently call the first with the name of the second. That definition of *closed* for a parametrized curve is a property that doesn't propagate to every reparametrization. Reparametrizations are not the same parametric curve. So, nothing to complain. There is no reason to expect reparametrizations to share all properties.

Comment: One could define when a curve, the topological space, is closed. One option is by saying that there exists a parametric curve that has it as image, and that is closed.

Comment: So $\gamma(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ is closed right? Graphing $\gamma(t')=(\cos(t^3+t), \sin(t^3+t))$ I get a circle; its closed as well.

Comment: You need to be clear of what is being called closed? Your two sentences are calling closed to two different types of objects. In the first sentence you are saying that a *parametric curve* is closed. This also implies that the image of that curve is closed. But in the second sentence the parametric curve, according to your book's definition, is not closed. What you can say in the second sentence is only that the image is closed.