# Not sure why the following reparametrization map is valid

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand why $(\cos(t^3 + t), \sin(t^3 + t))$ is a valid reparametrization of the circle $(\cos(t), \sin(t))$ (more discussion is provided here: [Finding an example of "A reparametrization of a closed curve need not be closed"$\text{}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485639/finding-an-example-of-a-reparametrization-of-a-closed-curve-need-not-be-closed?noredirect=1&lq=1)). To be specific, I'm working under the assumption that both the reparametrization and its inverse need to be smooth. While $p(t) = t^3 + t$ most certainly is smooth, its inverse is not differentiable at the origin. Is the non-differentiability problem evaded by considering any continuous interval of length $2\pi$ which does not contain zero?

Comment: Since $p'(t) = 3t^2 +1$ is always non-zero, $p^{-1}$ is indeed differentiable.

Comment: @ArcticChar Ah, true! But then what fails in the following reasoning: We can apply the Cardano's method for finding the inverse of $p(t) = t^3 + t$, which will end up being an equation involving a cube root, which in turn is not differentiable at $0$?